# How to get .wav file from ADC chip?

Tags: python

I have ADC chip 24 bit 5MHz working with Arduino. I use it to digitize sound from electret microphone and it gives me binary code which I wanna convert into an uncompressed .wav file. How can I do this? Should I install some drivers to connect them to USB (COM) port?
Thanks (Sorry, if my english leaves a lot to be desired, cuz I'm not English)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the serial output from the arduino to output back to the computer each value received. Then use Python's serial library as referenced [here](http://playground.arduino.cc/interfacing/python). Then use the wave library for which details can be found [here](http://blog.acipo.com/wave-generation-in-python/). If any more help is required, add your code so far to your post then we can help with bugs etc. Also, most arduinos I've come across have a 12 bit (??) ADC onboard that's perfectly good.

Comment: Do I have to apply this "coversion" every time I record sound? Probably I have to create a program which will do it automatically? 
Yes, as far as I know, most Arduinos have a 10 bit ADC, but to digitize sound professionally it's too few.

Comment: Just live convert, sorry for the late reply I was on holiday :P you've probably sorted it by now.

Comment: You know, I'm waiting for my chip, which I ordered from Aliexpress, cuz the old one didn't suit. And, I hope, I found a solution. Just to reflash my Arduino with a hex file and my arduino will be accepted as an external USB card. That's it. But still thank you very much!